# UIWebView loadData and iWork Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am attempting to open an iWork 10 Numbers file placed on a Web site into a UIWebView. I tried with the following, and what happens is that the UIWebView loads blank. If I download the file to local the Documents folder and then load it in the UIWebView it then works. I'd like to read an iWork file without downloading them...

FYI, I have no issues with PDF, PPT, DOC, XLS...

Can anyone tell me how to load an iWork file from NSdata to UIWebView?

```
[webView loadData:receivedData 
    MIMEType:file.mediaMimetype 
    textEncodingName:nil 
    baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:PATHTOFILE] 
];
```

The tested values for mediaMimetype are:

- application/vnd.apple.numbers
- application/x-iwork-numbers-sffnumbers

Comment: Did you have any success yet with this?

Comment: Who were you user375584? What did you see?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compress iWork file with .zip extension to display in webview.

refer this link for detail:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html